# Bytes computation Javascript

Tags: javascript

yesterday a friend was complaining how in Bash he couldn't properly sort a list of elements because the method he was calling ended with a return statement.

Eventually the `return` instruction in Bash always returns a defined amount of bytes, and this was the reason of his concerns.

My question is:

How do I work with memory allocation in Javascript? How do I know how many bytes commands like `void 0` or `undefined` are?

That's pretty low level and I know JS is not supposed for these kind of tasks, yet I was curious on which could be the best way to approach this research.

Comment: If you need to measure the memory, number of objects etc. you can use a memory profiler inside developer tools (for example in IE, make the snapshots, compare them etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You simply don't allocate memory in JS - the environment does it for you. You cannot micro-manage it, and it does absolutely not matter how many bytes a value takes. If you really needed to know, you'll have to look at the implementation of the engine you are using; and for the exact size of particular values in your application you can take a heap snapshot with a profiler.

Comment: Well, you ought to *care* about it -- too many high-memory operations will still slow down your code. But you don't need to *manage* it.

Comment: @Blazemonger: Ok, yeah, you shouldn't write memory-leaking code of course. Clarified my answer.